# How to delete all the files except for one directory while creating a docker image

Tags: docker

I am pushing all the source code inside then i'm creating a build out of it. Then i want to delete all the sourceCode inside the image. How can i do that.

```
FROM node:18.17.1

WORKDIR /app


COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
COPY src/ ./src/
COPY .env ./

RUN npm install


RUN npm run build
RUN User shopt -s extglob ; rm -rf !(build) # this give me errors

EXPOSE 4000


CMD ["node", "build/app.js"]
```

also this is not working too.

```
find . -mindepth 1 ! -name 'build' -exec rm -r {} +
```

this gives me filenames and says file can't deleted because not exists...
so annoying

Comment: For what you're doing a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) would be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks to add exact error message(s) by editing your post

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `sh` and `bash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Docker multi-stage build for this case.  Instead of trying to delete files from an image, tell Docker to start over from a new image, and then copy in the built files from the old image.

```
# Build stage is exactly what you show already
FROM node:18.17.1 AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install  # move this earlier to avoid reinstalling packages on rebuilds

COPY tsconfig.json ./
COPY src/ ./src/
COPY .env ./

RUN npm run build

# For the second stage, re-install packages and
# copy in the built application
FROM node:18.17.1
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV=production
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY .env ./
COPY --from=build /app/build/ ./build/

# Then set metadata to run the image
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["node", "build/app.js"]
```

Internally, a Docker image consists of a sequence of *layers*.  Whenever you have a `RUN` command, Docker keeps all of the previous image and also records whatever's changed from the new step.  That is, a new `RUN` line always makes the image larger, even if you `RUN rm ...`, and a motivated user can extract the deleted content from the previous layer.

The multi-stage build starts over from a base image, re-installs library dependencies, and then `COPY --from=build` the built application.  The original source code was never in this image, so it's not part of the final image.  This sequence also means that you can install only the `dependencies` into the final image's `node_modules` directory, and not the `devDependencies`.  I also haven't copied the Typescript setup into the final image because it's not needed there.

Comment: thank you for your advise. I will try this

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

before `rm` command.

Check:

```
man bash | less +/'Pathname Expansion'
```

Comment: You can send him to man bash under *Pathname Expansion / Pattern Matching / The special pattern characters ...* for reference.

Comment: Added man bash part